# Inconsistent rendering of nested react-redux-connected components

Tags: reactjs, redux

I think we've been bitten by [this issue](https://github.com/rackt/redux/issues/125) (Strategy for avoiding cascading renders), but I don't know quite what to do about it.

In short, a child component is receiving property updates and executing a parent's bound render callback before the parent has received its prop updates. The result is that the callback uses stale properties and we get inconsistent rendering.

Here's a rough representation:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  renderHeader = () => {
    return <<uses this.props to render a header>>
  }

  render () {
    return ( <Child renderHeader={this.renderHeader}/> )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return Object.assign({}, state.tree.branch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Parent);


...


class Child extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      ...
        this.props.renderHeader()
      ...
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return Object.assign({}, state.tree.branch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Child);
```

I can make this work by passing props to the callback explicitly or by just avoid this pattern, but I feel like there's a larger concept/pattern/anti-pattern going on here that I'm failing to understand. Questions:

- Is it actually invalid to connect both components to the state tree?
- Is there clear logic for whether parents or children receive props first?

Comment: The store appears to notify subscribers in the order they were added.  Not quite sure how parent/child rendering sequence plays into that, exactly.  As for the rendering issue: presumably the combined props of `state.tree.branch` + `renderHeader` aren't actually changing, so React-Redux's default implementation of `shouldComponentUpdate()` sees no change and skips rendering.

That said, having a child component use a callback to do rendering seems... odd.  Why not have the parent render the header, and pass THAT to the child instead, either directly as a prop or as a nested component?

Comment: Reordering fixed the issue, but I'm not 100% sure we haven't done this elsewhere. Plus, ListView also requires a [`renderHeader` bound callback](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#renderheader). It isn't immediately apparent that it shouldn't be connected. The linked issue says something about batchedUpdates in which "parents will reconcile first so that the children render only once (with the newest props from their parent and their newest state)." Not what we're seeing? And yes, passing the rendered component as a prop might solve it. Thanks for the thoughts!